# I cant copy a file in the var/www directory

Tags: php, mediawiki

I installed mediawiki on a Lubuntu virtual machine which is running on virtualbox.

I configured and installed the mediawiki and now I need to copy the `localsettings.php` file in the `var/www` directory. I do this by using the terminal this is my code/scrypt:

```
wiki@wiki-Virtual:~$ sudo cp localsettings.php /var/www
cp: cannot stat ‘localsettings.php’: No such file or directory
```

I also tried to write the full path to the file but I get:

```
wiki@wiki-Virtual:~$ sudo cp /home/wiki/Desktop/localsettings.php /var/www
cp: cannot stat ‘/home/wiki/Desktop/localsettings.php’: No such file or directory
```

Can you help me to do the final step in installing the mediawiki? Also I can use some tips on working with the wiki on lubuntu.

Comment: Can you use 'ls /home/wiki/Desktop' and see localsettings.php listed?

Comment: Yes i can see the file listed but stil: wiki@wiki-Virtual:~$ sudo cp /home/wiki/Desktop/localsettings.php /var/www
[sudo] password for wiki: 
cp: cannot stat ‘/home/wiki/Desktop/localsettings.php’: No such file or directory
or
wiki@wiki-Virtual:~$ sudo cp localsettings.php /var/www
cp: cannot stat ‘localsettings.php’: No such file or directory

What can i do to copy the file in the var/www directory?!

Comment: Please add the output of 'ls -l /home/wiki/Desktop/'

Comment: Just a hunch, but you are aware that Linux is case-sensitive? So for example `localsettings.php` is a different file from `Localsettings.php`, or from `localsettings.PHP`.

Answer (score 0):

The file that you need to copy is actually called `LocalSettings.php`, not `localsettings.php`. Capitalization matters on Linux, so that's why you're getting the error.

This means the following should work:

```
sudo cp LocalSettings.php /var/www
```

Comment: Or better `cp LocalSettings.php /var/www/`